# First logo is fading out but Second logo is not fading in ... on scroll down. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've finally figured out how to get my first logo to fade out to reveal the second logo on scroll down.  The idea is that as the user begins to scroll down, the first logo will fade out while the second logo fades in. I'm wanting a seamless, fluid transition from one logo to the other.  But what I have now is the first logo slowing fading out and then the second logo just appearing without a gradual fade-in ... though I including what I believed to be the correct code for the proper fade-in effect.  What have I done wrong?   Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <div id="full_logo"> <img src="images/logo_6_small.png" alt="full_logo" /></div>
</div> 

<header>
  <div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <div id="nav_left">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="Claire_logo">
      <img src="images/logo_6_small.png" alt="logo2" id="logo_Claire" class="logo_main" style="display:none" />
      <img src="images/logo_bluebird_90_cc.png" alt="logo1" id="logo_Claire_blue" class="logo" />
     </a>
     <div id="nav_right">
       <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
       <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
       <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</header>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 0) {
        $('#logo_Claire_blue').fadeOut(800, function() {
          $('#logo_Claire_blue').replaceWith('<div id="full_logo"><img src="images/logo_6_small.png" alt="full_logo"/></div>').fadeIn(800);
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I don't know for sure but I think since you use replaceWith the fadeIn is not triggered correctly. Can you try appending it to the container (using `.html()` or `append()` in jquery) with the `full_logo` div and then calling fadeIn?

Comment: `.hide(0).fadeIn(800)` this is for quick help .. But your way isn't the right way to do what you want

Comment: [fadeOut()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) calls the callback *after* the animation finishes. I'd start there.

Comment: I'm a novice with not enough experience and knowledge with js/jquery.  I'm using code someone on this site gave me and it's not working. I don't know a better way to do it and don't understand the instructions in some of these comments.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef   Could you show me what you mean?

Comment: @Vienne sorry for my previous comment to use `add/removeClass` because I misunderstood your question .. see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Why are you replacing HTML when you already have your logo in the code? Replace the code of the `if (scroll > 0)` with this:

```
 $('#logo_Claire_blue').fadeOut(800);
 setTimeout(function() {
    $('#logo_Claire').fadeIn(800);
 }, 600)
```

First it fades the displayed logo, then, with a delay set by `setTimeout`, it triggers the fade in of the second one. For better transition lower the setTimeout to something like 500, but then, you need to play with the logos positions in the DOM in order for the new to be over the old one and not next to it or on top (`position: relative`, `position: absolute`)

Comment: This is helping. Thank you.   My logo positions are good but the transition is still a bit jumpy. I'll play with the numbers and try to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `.eq()` to change between logos
- Use `.stop()` to stop repeat the animation.. *Try to remove it to see*
- You change between `eq(0)` and `eq(1)` up to your need

**Example 1**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 0) {
        $('a.Claire_logo img').eq(1).stop().fadeOut(200 , function(){
          $('a.Claire_logo img').eq(0).stop().fadeIn(200);
        });
      }else{
         $('a.Claire_logo img').eq(0).stop().fadeOut(200 , function(){
          $('a.Claire_logo img').eq(1).stop().fadeIn(200);
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
header{
  position : fixed;
  top : 0;
}
main{
  height : 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <div id="nav_left">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="Claire_logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Visit+Blogging.com+Now" alt="logo2" id="logo_Claire" class="logo_main" style = "display : none;"/>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x60?text=Visit+Blogging.com+Now" alt="logo1" id="logo_Claire_blue" class="logo" />
     </a>
     <div id="nav_right">
       <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
       <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
       <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main></main>
```

**Example 2** using `attr("src")`

- You can use only one `<img>` tag and change `src` attribute of it
- Use `.stop()` to stop repeat the animation.. *Try to remove it to see*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var Check = false;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > 0 && Check == false){
      Check = true;
      $('a.Claire_logo > img').stop().fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).attr("src" ,"https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Visit+Blogging.com+Now").fadeIn(300);
      });
    }else if(scroll <= 0){
      Check = false;
      $('a.Claire_logo > img').stop().fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).attr("src" ,"https://via.placeholder.com/100x60?text=Visit+Blogging.com+Now").fadeIn(300);
      });
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
header{
  position : fixed;
  top : 0;
}
main{
  height : 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <div id="nav_left">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="Claire_logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x60?text=Visit+Blogging.com+Now" alt="logo2" id="logo_Claire" class="logo_main"/>
     </a>
     <div id="nav_right">
       <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
       <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
       <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main></main>
```

**Example 3** You need to work around the css style to avoid the delay between both images places

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Check = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 0 && Check == false) {
        Check = true;
        $('a.Claire_logo img').eq(1).stop().fadeOut(800);
        $('a.Claire_logo img').eq(0).stop().fadeIn(800);
      }else if(scroll <= 0 && Check == true){
        Check = false;
        $('a.Claire_logo img').eq(0).stop().fadeOut(800);
        $('a.Claire_logo img').eq(1).stop().fadeIn(800);
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
header{
  position : fixed;
  top : 0;
}
main{
  height : 2000px;
}

.Claire_logo{
  position : relative;
  height : 60px;
  display : block;
}
.Claire_logo > img{
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  height : 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <div id="nav_left">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="Claire_logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Visit+Blogging.com+Now" alt="logo2" id="logo_Claire" class="logo_main" style="display : none;"/>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x60?text=Visit+Blogging.com+Now" alt="logo1" id="logo_Claire_blue" class="logo" />
     </a>
     <div id="nav_right">
       <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
       <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
       <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main></main>
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help but this isn't what I'm going for.  Even in your own example there is a long delay before the fade-out of logo 1 occurs and then it fades out completely. It slowly disappears and then logo 2 quickly appears. I'm wanting a fluid transition from logo 1 to logo 2 as soon as the user begins to scroll.  Logo 1 should fade out and logo 2 fade in with the same speed - Not logo 1 fading out slowly, disappearing and logo 2 quickly appearing.

Comment: @Vienne answer Updated